# Copy Database table to Excel

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I want to copy a database table with column headers to excel from within Visual Studio Community 2015. I have Sql server data tools ( ver 14) installed. However when I choose Open Data table in server explorer and right click on the grey upper left corner I do not get any options.
I have set checked Include column headers when copying or saving the results.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just select the data, copy it (Ctrl-C) and paste it to Excel, but it will be very slow (took about 1 minute for just 1000 records) and it does not copy column names.

If you are using a SQL Server Database, one better way to export this data is using SQL Server Management Studio's (SSMS) export wizard, as indicated [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/202/simple-way-to-export-data-from-sql-server/).

Comment: Ctrl-C does not copy the headers. When I try to attach the local .mdf file in SSMS it does not show the file to select.

Answer (score 0):

I have used New Query (Right click on table), wrote a SQL query (eg : Select * from kultivars). I then copied the the result from the results tab. (right click). It gives the option "Copy with headers"

Comment: The same as SQL Server Management Studio actually. But that's not what the title asked - if you want to export data to Excel, you don't use copy/paste. Use the export wizard, save the package and execute it as often as you want. Alexei's answer was correct